# iPhone tableview & searchbar hiding

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a tableview with a search bar at the very top. I hide this under the status bar using UIEdgeInserts until the user pulls down the table view. It works as expected.

My problem is that when I navigate away from this screen and back again using segues the searchbar and edge inserts are displayed for a split second and then hide :( Can anyone suggest a possible solution please?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:TRUE];
[self.searchBar setDelegate:self];
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.searchBar setTranslucent:YES];

[self.listingTable setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self.listingTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
}
```

I tried placing the setContentOffset into the viewWillAppear method but it does not work.

Comment: are you using iOS <5 version???????

Comment: @MountainLion nope, iOS5 and above